# How do I prove this nice inequality $x+3\sqrt[3]{xy^2}\geq4\sqrt{xy} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $x,y\geq0$. Prove that:
>   $$
>   x+3\sqrt[3]{xy^2}\geq4\sqrt{xy}
> $$

**Note**: It's seems easy but when I tried to show it I went to complicated formula.

Comment: What's nice about it?!

Comment: It just follows from the [AM-GM inequality](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean_Inequality), see zeraoulia's answer below.

Comment: For future reference, if direct manipulations seem to make things more complicated, look for a change of variables to eliminate some clutter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint :$x+3\sqrt[3]{xy^2}=x+\sqrt[3]{xy^2}+\sqrt[3]{xy^2}+\sqrt[3]{xy^2}\ge 4\sqrt[4]{x\cdot\sqrt[3]{xy^2}\cdot\sqrt[3]{xy^2}\cdot\sqrt[3]{xy^2}}=4\sqrt{xy}$